# Searchview clear button issue

Tags: android

I'm having an issue in search view.

The clear button is not at right end part of the search view.

**How can I place it to the right side of the view?**

[image]

This is my menu item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
        android:title="Search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />
</menu>
```

My code in activity

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));

        if (null != searchView) {
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                    .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
            searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        }

        SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return true;
            }

            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }
        };
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }
```

Comment: This is how it shows up on Tablets.

Comment: not just on tablets but on any landscape orientation

Answer (score 6):

try with this

```
searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```